# Conversion between google.protobuf.Timestamp and std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>

Tags: c++, time, protocol-buffers, c++-chrono, measure

I'm trying to properly convert a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` (C++) to a `google.protobuf.Timestamp` (protocol buffers) and back again to a steady_clock.

I would prefer it to be represented in nanosecond resolution as the data I plan to serialize / deserialize are timestamped measurements which will be evaluated in a different context.

As I fail to find a definitive standard of the epoch time for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` I wonder if anyone else have tried it out?

Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` holds about the same information as a hand-held stopwatch.  It has no relationship to the civil calendar or UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-) I'll have to rethink since I've mixed up the concepts.

Comment: If you want to relate the protobuf timestamp to UTC then using `chrono::system_clock::time_point` would be appropriate.  It will be important to know if the protobuf timestamp is UTC, local or related to some other time zone.